# Python - ctrl L does not work

Tags: python, python-idle, ctrl

Attempting to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> for clearing Power Sheel in *Python 2.7.8* I get no response.

Is there any problem in *Windows 10*?

Answer (score 8):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> only works on Linux/OS X terminals. It does not work on Windows. To clear the screen on Windows you could do the following:

```
import os
os.system('cls')
```

If you're using IDLE on Windows there is not a way to clear it. As a workaround you can use:

```
print('\n' * 80)
```

Comment: This will not work in IDLE's Shell or any similar GUI-based IDE because IDLE uses tkinter for its windows and the 'cls' terminal command only works with Windows' terminals and knows nothing about tcl/tk or other GUI windows.

Comment: What is going to work in Python IDLE? os.system('cls') returns zero value.

Comment: @GeorgeKouskoulis IDLE does not support clearing the screen AFAIK. The best you could do is probably something like `print('\n' * 80)` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

To extend Kredns answer to Linux/OS X terminals as well:

```
import os
os.system('clear')
```

Answer (score 0):

I like Kredns's answer, however, you have to type all of that every time.
I made a module/function.
Okay, I am using Python 3.7.3, but similar answer for Python 2.

```
def cls():
    import os
    os.system('cls')
    return
```

Save this as a script and import cls or whatever you want to call it. Import that (e.g. on python start up). So if you're in the correct directory:

```
from cls import cls
```

Then call it with cls() whenever you want to clear the screen.

```
cls()
```

Answer (score 0):

IdleX extension of IDLE has the functionality you are looking for.
Try installing from here
http://idlex.sourceforge.net/
OR
https://pypi.org/project/idlex/

pressing CTRL-L, works in the intutive way (clear the console and take you to the top with a prompt, and doesn't clear the variables and definitions you have defined yet)