# Clear screen with CMD disabled

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to clear the screen in my Idle text editor (the default one that comes with python  (and is basically command prompt anyway).

I have had this problem for a while now and i've searched just about every corner of the web but nothing has truly answered my problem.

```
import subprocess 
import subprocess as sp 
import os
os.system('cls')
does not work
Ctrl + L does not work
clearing modules also do not work
```

Using this for loading screens, animations etc... would be a dream com true so if anyone can find a way to do this it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42721491/python-ctrl-l-does-not-work . This might help you

Comment: @Crazy2crack Thanks so much for trying to help much appreciated. Unfortunately all the answers in the forum you linked suggest using the os module. This does mean using cmd. Error 255 indicates the user needs elevated perms to execute this. Similarly, the default terminal for all windows computers is cmd and cannot be changed to powershell as this is just how the computer is built. With sublime text, (an editor that uses root to execute code) without elevated permissions it can not be done. I hope this correlation can be seen as an analogy to my problem.